# Is there a way to convert/recover a feature class that was edited in a higher ESRI license to work with it in lower license?

Tags: arcmap, license

I have a geodatabase where one of the feature classes was edited using an Advanced license, but I work in a Basic license and when I go to edit the feature class I am unable to.

Are there any tricks to copying this feature class into a new one in order to be able to edit the data in Basic instead of Advanced?  I tried copy/pasting the feature class within the GDB but got an ESRI license error.  Short of building a new feature class from scratch with the exact same schema and then copy/pasting the records over, is there any other way to get around the license limitation to just edit the data's spatial?

Comment: This question does not make sense. Basic license users should always be able to access data edited by higher-level licenses. What you can't do is edit data to which you license does to permit editing. Please edit the question to specify the exact type of data involved, and if enterprise geodatabase, which exact RDBMS.

Comment: This sounds like an advanced option like relationships or topology is lurking somewhere. If so, you will have to use import or export to get the data away from those options. Then it should be editable.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the feature was edited and linked anno mistakenly created.  So the fix was to duplicate the feature class, remove the links, delete the old feature class and then rename the duplicate to the original filename to retain links.